# how can i keep my user logged in when i change pages ? PHP

Tags: php, authentication

im using a log-in page :

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if($row['password']==md5($upass))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
        <?php
    }

}
?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ورود</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="login-form">
<form method="post">
<table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="btn-login">ورود</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="register.php">ثبت نام</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

if i enter the username and password correctly i go to welcome page but im logged in just in that page and when i go to another page im like a guest user again.

how do i fix it and stay logged in every where ?

Comment: User `session_start()` in every page!

Comment: Make sure that you have added *session_start();* at top of the other pages too. It will be a good practice if you add common functions like db connection, session_start etc... to a separate page and include it wherever needed.

Comment: where do you check if `$_SESSION['user']` is set and load the user from the db? Also it may not hurt to explicit call a `session_write_close` when you log the user in bevor the header redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Starting session on top of each page will solve your problem.

Then keep a check on $_SESSION['user']. If its present show logged in user else redirect to login page.